# Transferring console Java application into Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, svn

I am at the beginning of process of trying to transfer existing simple Spring Java console application into Maven. It isn't much complicated app, few Java classes, unit tests a and library dependencies.

I have a plan of these following steps - please correct me if is there some nonsense.

1. Checkout app from SVN repository
2. Create a empty app from some suitable Maven archetype (do you know some appropriate?)
3. Copy existing java application sources into new app structure
4. Edit pom.xml and define dependencies et cetera.
5. Create Eclipse project - `mvn eclipse:eclipse` (until now we used Netbeans, but we are moving to Eclipse)
6. Commit

Is there some best practices what do do and what do avoid from your experiences?

Comment: If it's your svn repo, you want to hang onto the commit history of each file - so try to use `svn mv` and do everything in the existing checkout

Comment: Yes, SVN history is and issue, I need to preserve all history.

Comment: In that case, @A4L's answer is good - if you have the SVN plugin installed in Eclipse when you move things, you'll keep the history

Comment: @artbristol moving inside of eclipse is just comfortable, it all comes down to a `svn mv` :). I wouldn't not advise to work with two different svn clients, except for the initial checkout and before importing into eclipse, and yet both have to support the same version of svn. Otherwise it's only trouble!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply convert your project from eclipse into a Maven Project

```
Right click on project > Configure > Convert to Maven Project
```

Assumint you have imported the project into eclipse and already installen the [m2e](http://eclipse.org/m2e/download/) plugin. A pom.xml will be created including all dependnecies.

Optionally create the standard directory structure for a maven project and move your files inside of eclipse, so that you keep the svn history of your project.

You jsut have then to commit the changes back to svn.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this

1. create an empty maven project from Eclipse: New -> Other -> Maven project
2. copy app sources to project's src/main/java and resources to src/main/resources
3. configure dependencies in pom.xml

Answer (score -1):

By the steps you had enumerated, I believe it's a nice approach. Nonetheless, I would recommend you to have a look into [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/).

In my opinion, Gradle is way better than Maven, and since you are starting with it, I think is a good idea to start with a better technology right away!
The [plugin for eclipse](https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle/), is developed by Spring.

A lot of huge projects have migrated from others tools to Gradle. Even Android now uses it. As concluion, I would say that as a best practice I would go to Gradle, instead of Maven.

Still, if you will want to use Maven, just be sure to configure the proxy (if you use one. Once, took me hours to figure it out why maven was not fetching the dependencies...), and your steps should work fine.